# devising a code for five symbols

Tags: coding-theory

Problem:
You need to send messages in the five symbols A, B, C, D, E. The frequencies of each symbol are in this order from most frequent to least frequent. Devise a code that will make the average length of messages as short as possible.

I know that A should have the shortest code, B the next shortest and so on with E having the longest code.

But I don't know what other constraints there are.
For example, how should I make it so that the code can be decodable?

In the same chapter, an example for encoding the genetic code was given, with the assignment as follows:

A 0

C 10

T 110

G 111

(order of frequency is A, C, T, G for genes)
Is there a way to turn this into a 5-symbol code?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: To make the average message length as short as possible, you'll need to know the actual frequencies of those five symbols. For example, the distribution (0.22, 0.21, 0.2, 0.19, 0.18) should be encoded differently than (0.9, 0.027, 0.026, 0.024, 0.023).

Comment: @Snowball In fact in extreme cases (such as $p(A)\approx1$) it may be advisable to encode longer *sequences*  of $A$ with the shortest one bit code word. I think nothing in the problem description prevents us from doing so

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that needs to be made to use a coding like that applied to the nucleotide bases is that not only are the probabilites decreasing from A to E, but they are decreasing *a lot*. Otherwise, you need to consider the probabilities explicitly. I'll call A,B,C... just $X_1, X_2, X_3...$ for simplicity.

But, if $p(X_i) \gg p(X_{i+1})$ then it is always beneficial to make the more probable one have relatively fewer characters if possible. For example, for $A,B,C,D$ we could choose 00,01,10,11, (this is efficient sometimes, and the usual choice with *equal* probabilities) but if $A$ was probable enough, it would be advantageous to use something where a is just one digit for A, even if it means the others must have more, for example A=0, B=100, C=110, D=111 would be better. In the extreme, if $A$ was really, really, really, probable ($p(A)\rightarrow\infty$), then the efficiency would be completely dominated by the number of characters used to represent $A$, regardless of the others.

If you apply the idea that $X_i$ is much more probable than $X_{i+1}$ to all the symbols, then you get:

$\begin{array}{cc}\text{Symbol}&\text{Code} \\ 
A & 0 \\ B & 10 \\ C & 110 \\ D & 1110 \\ E & 1111
\end{array}$

Much like the DNA code. Think of each string of $1$s representing a number by their length, and the $0$ signifying the end of it. For the longest one, just having 4 $1$s is enough to indicate the end of the number.

---

Without thinking about it more, I'm not sure of the exact conditions for this to apply. Though probably it is **something like**  $p(X_i)/p(X_{i+1}) > 2$ (*I haven't checked it is correct at all!!!!!*)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use what is known as a [prefix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), meaning that no code is a prefix for another code. For example, $\{1,61,766,7716\}$ is a valid prefix code because no single code is a prefix to another. An example of an invalid prefix code is $\{1,61,617,1776\}$, because $1$ is a prefix to $1776$, and $61$ is a prefix to $617$.

One simple solution to your problem is to do the following:

$$A\space{0}$$
$$B\space{10}$$
$$C\space{110}$$
$$D\space{1110}$$
$$E\space{11110}$$

This is a valid prefix code. The more frequently a character is used, the less bits it uses. But, if you wanted to devise a more precise code (for example, A has a frequency "score" of $8$, B has a "score" of $6$, C has a "score" of $5$, etc.) a [Huffman code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) can be built using a binary tree.

Comment: E should be 1111 not 11110 - you dont need a "stop" character as it is implicit when you have enough 1s

Comment: @Lucas It doesn't "need" to be $1111$. It's still a valid prefix code either way.

Comment: indeed, but it is shorter, and the *shortest* with $p(A)\gg p(B) \gg p(C) ...$

Comment: Formally, you don't *need*, but it is sufficient that the code be a prefix code. Note that e.g. $1776611$ is still uniquely decodeable as $1776,61,1$; in general, to decode something encoded using $\{1,61,617,1776\}$, note that two $7$ in a rrow can only come from $1776$, any other $7$ can only come from $617$, any remaining $6$ can only come from $61$, all that remains must be $1$s. The task required only unique decodability.